# How to color outline differently from fill in histogram using ggplot / R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Please find `My data q` below

I have produced the following plot:

[image]

By using the script:

```
library(tidyverse)
w %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Studie=as.character(Studie),
         best.resp =as.factor(best.resp)) %>% 
  bind_rows(., mutate(., Studie="all")) %>% 
  count(Studie, best.resp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Studie, n, fill= best.resp))  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "purple", "yellow")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red","orange")) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0))
```

I want the outline around each bar to have one set of colors while the fill to have another set of colors. As you can see, I tried using `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_colour_manual`, however, that does not solve my problem.

I have attached a picture illustrating what I mean by outlines having one color and the fill another color:

[image]

```
My data 
q <- structure(list(Studie = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), best.resp = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L)), .Names = c("Studie", 
"best.resp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -106L))
```

Comment: If you want to change the fill, you have to assign a variable to fill in `aes`. Likewise if you want to change the color, you have to assign something to color. You've only assigned fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your code you have a w %>%  is it supposed to be q?

You need to specify color in your aes command. Right now, you just have the fill-- so the scale color manual later, doesn't apply to anything.

```
q %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Studie=as.character(Studie),
         best.resp =as.factor(best.resp)) %>% 
  bind_rows(., mutate(., Studie="all")) %>% 
  count(Studie, best.resp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Studie, n, color = best.resp, fill= best.resp))  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "purple", "yellow")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red","orange")) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to map a variable to the colour aesthetic (in aes):

```r
ggplot(aes(Studie, n, fill= best.resp, colour = best.resp)
```